# Performance in jQuery with selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was wondering things...

If i need to get the content or append an click function to an div, as the structure of the selectors it's something like that:

```
$('body #content #sidebar .modalwindow #global-content')
```

i want to target #global-content, the final id of the selectors.
what its better?
Just target it as $('#global-content') and do what i wanna or give to it all the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a similar question was asked in

[jQuery Selectors, efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262116/jquery-selectors-efficiency)

the answer is that

$('#global-content')

is faster

Answer (score 2):

$('#global-content') is the best selector to use, *altough maybe the whole selector will be executed the same way (if jQuery starts from right to left, which I'm not sure it does)*. ID should be unique and `getElementById()` is the fastest native browser method, so `$('#global-content')` is the fastest possible selector.

Keep in mind also, that when you are searching for something exactly 1 level lower in the DOM tree, you can put > in the selector. Example:

`$('body .content')` is equialent to `$('body').find('.content')`

`$('body > .content')` is equialent to `$('body').children('.content')`

The second one is faster.

Comment: $('body .content') is equialent to $('body').find('.content')
$('body > .content') is equialent to $('body').children('.content')

Answer (score 2):

You can experiment and try out your selectors [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-tests)

Answer (score 1):

if you know the `id` of your element and if your id is **really unique** (as it should be). It is faster to call directly the `id` >> `$('#global-content')`.

Thus, it is interpreted by jquery to one of the fastest selector `getElementById()` instead of filtering the DOM.

*Note:* I know jquery 1.5 and higher (maybe even since 1.4) were optimized to select by `id` even if the jquery code was adding too much information but that's not the best way to rely on the framework to correct a bad coding