# apply each function for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have two elements with the same ID on one page. When I attempt to append the data in each element into the corresponding div, it appends the data from the first element into both divs.

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="data" class="democlass" data-author="Mr. Jhon Doe" data-cat="Technology" data-url="http://www.youtube.com/"></div>
<div class="post">    
    <p class="data-author"></p>
    <p class="data-cat"></p>
    <a href="#" class="data-url"></a>
</div>    

<div id="data" class="democlass" data-author="Mrs. Mona" data-cat="Personal" data-url="http://www.google.com/"></div>
    <div class="post">
        <p class="data-author"></p>
        <p class="data-cat"></p>
        <a href="#" class="data-url"></a>
    </div>
```

Here's the jQuery I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $ele = $("#data");
    $( ".data-author" ).append($ele.attr("data-author"));
    $( ".data-cat" ).append($ele.attr("data-cat"));
    $( ".data-url" ).append($ele.attr("data-url"));
$(".data-url").attr('href' , 'http://example.com/test/' + $ele.data('url'))
});
```

How can append the first element's data to the first `.post`, and the second element's data to the second `.post`?

A working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZXqdg) for test

Comment: ids are meant to be unique

Comment: You should not ever have two elements on the page with the same `id`.  Change your markup to have unique IDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme - your jquery may not work as expected when you have multiple items with the same ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)

Comment: use classes if you want multiple items with the same "identifier"

Comment: is it also occurs to class?

Comment: Like folks said above, you shouldn't use same id for multiple markups. However, if you are adamant to go against the standard, wrap each div with id="data" with another div and then reference in jquery as a child.

Comment: @bona classes are meant to group different items togheter. So you can have many items with the same class

Comment: @LelioFaieta but if use the same class as identifier, il will use the first `class` as the data to append and ignore the next `class`, right?

Comment: Everyone here is focusing on the multiple ID's - but that's not relevant to the *question*.  The elements already have a class that can be leveraged.  @bona see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your markup so that you have unique ID's.  The `ID` attributes is intended to be unique.  Use a `class` to group elements together that you would like to handle in a certain way.

Note that if you DO use the same ID across multiple elements, [jQuery may not do what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498617) - so especially avoid the same ID when using jQuery / javascript.

But - to answer your *question*, which is not about multiple IDs with the same value, but rather how to cause data to be populated from multiple elements into the relevant div:

Use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
// no-conflict-mode safe document ready shorthand
jQuery(function() {
  // get the items by class instead of id
  var $items = $(".democlass");
  // loop over the items
  $items.each(function() {
    // load $post with the desired div with the class of .post
    var $post = $(this).next('.post');
    // put the data into the html
    $post.find(".data-author").text($(this).attr("data-author"));
    $post.find(".data-cat").text($(this).attr("data-cat"));
    $post.find(".data-url").text($(this).attr("data-url"));
    $post.find(".data-url").attr('href', 'http://example.com/test/' + $(this).data('url'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data" class="democlass" data-author="Mr. Jhon Doe" data-cat="Technology" data-url="http://www.youtube.com/"></div>
<div class="post">
  <p class="data-author"></p>
  <p class="data-cat"></p>
  <a href="#" class="data-url"></a>
</div>
<div id="data" class="democlass" data-author="Mrs. Mona" data-cat="Personal" data-url="http://www.google.com/"></div>

<div class="post">
  <p class="data-author"></p>
  <p class="data-cat"></p>
  <a href="#" class="data-url"></a>
</div>
```