# jquery click, toggle one or more div block

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a jQuery when clicked on div #toggle, span inside div will show and when set to toggle mode, but when I use two or more div blocks, it only shows the first span. please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#show").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='toggle'>this clicked
  <span id='show'><p>Show this</p></span>
</div>
<div id='toggle'>
  <span id='show'><p>fhslkjklsfjl</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: use class as id should be unique!

Comment: Vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Or better: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-jquery-works-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id='toggle'>this clicked
      <span id='show'><p>Show this</p></span>
    </div>
    <div id='toggle'>2 nd button
      <span id='show'><p>fhslkjklsfjl</p></span>
    </div>

       $("div#toggle").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
    $(this).find("#show").toggle();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9oh6yqfn/9/

Comment: IDs should always be unique in HTML. In case you want to use same name across DOM elements, you should use class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same id. **ID should be unique**.

**Try by giving class:**

```js
  $(".toggle").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
    $(this).find("#show").toggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle'>this clicked
  <span id='show'><p>Show this</p></span>
</div>
<div class='toggle'>2 nd button
  <span id='show'><p>fhslkjklsfjl</p></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have same id for both spans. Try using different id's for span.
For eg:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#show").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='toggle'>this clicked
  <span id='show'><p>Show this</p></span>
</div>
<div id='toggle'>
  <span id='show1'><p>fhslkjklsfjl</p></span>
</div>
```