# Not able to display data on change of drop down values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table whose data is being filled dynamically. Each row has a drop-down under status section from which user can select a value and according to the selected value, some input boxes have to be displayed, but these boxes should be displayed in that row in which the drop-down belonged. So, if the drop-down belongs to the first row then the box should appear in the first row only and if the drop-down belongs to the second row then the box should appear in the second row only

Currently, the code that I am using is displaying the input boxes randomly in different rows irrespective of the dropdown position

Can anyone please tell how this can be corrected
HTML Code

```
<table class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($student as $per_student): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $per_student->name; ?></td>
        <td>
          <select class="can-dd" onchange="myFunction(this)" name="status">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="Accepted ">Accepted</option>
            <option value="Forwarded ">Forwarded </option>
            <option value="Schedule">Schedule </option>
            <option value="Custom">Custom</option> 
          </select>
          <div class="schedule">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="schedule" name="schedule">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>

          <div class="custom">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="custom"  name="custom">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>

          <div class="submit_value">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;
    if(value == 'Schedule'){
      jQuery('.custom').remove();
      jQuery('.submit_value').remove();
      $(".schedule").show();
    }
    else if(value == 'Custom'){     
      jQuery('.schedule').remove();
      jQuery('.submit_value').remove();
      $(".custom").show();
    }
    else{
      jQuery('.schedule').remove();
      jQuery('.custom').remove();
      $(".submit_value").show();  
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `id`s within the document are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @Teemu can you please elaborate

Comment: PHP `foreach` loop creates the elements in `tr`s with hardcoded `id`s. When you refer an element like `jQuery('#custom')`, jQuery finds the first element with that `id` from the document only.

Comment: To elaborate. You can only have one unique ID per element otherwise it will cause errors when you try to execute a script targetting that ID. You cannot have two elements that share the same ID.

Comment: You can read more about html id's here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @Teemu k got the point and made the changes can you please have a look if it is done properly

Comment: @Teemu can you please show through code how to do it

Comment: Where is your JS?

Comment: @hungrykoala it is in the post at the bottom

Comment: oops sorry didn't saw clearly the scrollbar. Try changing `myFunction(event)` to this `myFunction(this)` also change all your id's to class since you're doing foreach for the elements chances are the ID will cause problems in the future.

Comment: @hungrykoala I converted it, but it is not working

Comment: @sammy Pass the `event` object, then declare `var parent = $(event.target).parent()` and replace every `jQuery/$` with `parent.find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code maybe this help you

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($student as $per_student): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $per_student->name; ?></td>
        <td>
          <select class="can-dd status_value"  name="status">
            <option value="">STATUS</option>
            <option value="Accepted ">Accepted</option>
            <option value="Forwarded ">Forwarded </option>
            <option value="Schedule">Schedule </option>
            <option value="Custom">Custom</option> 
          </select>
          <div class="schedule input_box">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="schedule" name="schedule">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>

          <div class="custom input_box">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="custom"  name="custom">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>

          <div class="submit_value input_box">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#mytable").on("change", ".status_value", function(){
        var selDiv = jQuery(this).parent("td");
        var selVal = jQuery(this).val();
        if(selVal == 'Schedule'){
            selDiv.find(".input_box").hide();
            selDiv.find(".schedule").show();
        } 
        else if(selVal == 'Custom'){
            selDiv.find(".input_box").hide();
            selDiv.find(".custom").show();
        } 
        else {
            selDiv.find(".input_box").hide();
            selDiv.find(".submit_value").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I had to remove IDs from all fields and set jQuery change event based on class for particular raw

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and check if it works for you. I have made some changes to the code but instead of generating the code trough `php`, I am doing it through `JavaScript` but it should not make much of a difference.

In your html file, you are generating rows where child `div`s share the same id `submit_value`, `custom`, `schedule`. You should change those id to be generated dynamically or remove them completely. I have removed them because to me, they seem unnecessary.

Here is a modified HTML file.

```
<tr>
  <td>--- PHP GENERATED NAME ---</td>
  <td>
    <select class="can-dd" onchange="myFunction(event)" name="status">
      <option value="">STATUS</option>
      <option value="Accepted ">Accepted</option>
      <option value="Forwarded ">Forwarded </option>
      <option value="Schedule">Schedule </option>
      <option value="Custom">Custom</option>
    </select>
    <div class="schedule">
      <input  type="text" placeholder="schedule" name="schedule">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="custom">
      <input  type="text" placeholder="custom"  name="custom">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="submit_value">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And here is a modified javascript code. The first part just generates the html, you can skip it. The `myFunction` part selects appropriate elements through `event.target` therefore you can target specific part of document instead of the whole document.

`event.target` is in your case the `select` element, therefore if you call `parentNode` on it, you get a corresponding row. By invoking `querySelector` on that row with some class name as a search query, you are searching for an element with that class, but only within the subtree of the current row.

```js
// just to dynamically generate the table
const generateTable = n => {
  const tBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let htmlCode = `<tr>
      <td>Some name</td>
      <td>
        <select class="can-dd" onchange="myFunction(event)" name="status">
          <option value="">STATUS</option>
          <option value="Accepted ">Accepted</option>
          <option value="Forwarded ">Forwarded </option>
          <option value="Schedule">Schedule </option>
          <option value="Custom">Custom</option>
        </select>
        <div class="schedule">
          <input  type="text" placeholder="schedule" name="schedule">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
        </div>

        <div class="custom">
          <input  type="text" placeholder="custom"  name="custom">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
        </div>

        <div class="submit_value">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  >SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>`
    tBody.innerHTML += htmlCode;
  }
}

function myFunction(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  if(value == 'Schedule'){
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.custom').remove();
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.submit_value').remove();
  }
  else if(value == 'Custom'){
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.schedule').remove();
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.submit_value').remove();
  }
  else{
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.schedule').remove();
    e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.custom').remove();
  }
}

generateTable(4);
```

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert and still in the learning phase, but I think I can try to provide a possible solution to this.

You have given id names like 'Schedule' and 'schedule' which are valid as they are case-sensitive in HTML. However, while calling these functions through CSS they are considered case-insensitive as mentioned in https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#casesens

Thus while using CSS #idname through jQuery '#schedule' can consider any of the tag named id = schedule or Schedule. When there are multiple tags with same id the results vary based on Browser. Referred to : [How jQuery works when there are multiple elements with the same "id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-jquery-works-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Try to give unique ids to all the elements and try the code.. It should solve the problem.