# control input field active status of form using toggle switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want the toggle switch to control the form fields when check, below is the sample code please suggest

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="lot-1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">x</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control numbersOnly" name="lot-1" id="lot-1" placeholder="Result" min="4"
            max="4">
        <div class="toggleWrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toggle1" class="mobileToggle" id="toggleField" checked value="true"
                data-id="lot-1">
            <label for="toggle1"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control numbersOnly" name="lot-2" id="lot-2" placeholder="Result" min="4"
            max="4">
        <div class="toggleWrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toggle1" class="mobileToggle" id="toggleField" checked value="true"
                data-id="lot-2">
            <label for="toggle1"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control numbersOnly" name="lot-3" id="lot-3" placeholder="Result" min="4"
            max="4">
    </div>
    <div class="toggleWrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle1" class="mobileToggle" id="toggleField" checked value="true" data-id="lot-3">
        <label for="toggle1"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is my jquery handler to make it functional

```
var fieldValue = false;

$('#toggleField').on('change', function(e) {
    var fieldId = $("#toggleField").attr('data-id');

    // console.log(fieldValue+fieldId);

    if (fieldValue === true) {
        // $("input[id=name]").attr('readonly',true);
        $('#lot-'+fieldId).attr('readonly',true);
    } else {
        $('#lot-'+fieldId).attr('readonly',false);
    }
});
```

I was testing to read the attribute data-id for each selected it will make the field disabled / read-only when unchecked by comparing the id with the data-id of respective input.

Comment: What? I am so confused.

Comment: Confused with what?

Comment: What the question?

Comment: And why do multiple elements have the same id?

Comment: the toggle field id is same for all 'toggleField' because i am calling it in my jquery where i will read the value when toggled to off (the state will be false) and look the data-id has a value lot-1, when this value is obtained after clicking the switch i will check the input field with the same id and disable it and again when toggled on back to active state and so on for other fields out there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498617/7886229

Comment: Two elements with the same id is never good or ok practice. Fix that issue and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code I changed the selector of change event `$('#toggleField')` to class name `$('.mobileToggle')` you have to remove Id attributes from checkboxes because it has the same id which is wrong
and get checked value dynamically to add and remove readonly attribute according to its value selector for inputs was wrong also `$('#lot-'+fieldId)` it has to be `$('#'+fieldId)` finally I fired change event manually to run it on first time page load you can add all this code inside document ready

```
$('.mobileToggle').on('change',function(e){

    var fieldId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var fieldValue = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(fieldValue == true){
        $('#'+fieldId).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    }else{
        $('#'+fieldId).removeAttr('readonly');
    }

  });
  $('.mobileToggle').change();
```

Comment: @BRAHMA welcome, if it works fine with you please accept the solution