# Dynamic load more button on multiple tables

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have two standard tables (maybe more in the future) with over 100 rows each. I've inserted a load more button for each table over 8 rows.

Only one button works (the first table). I assume I need to assign this code for EACH table for it to work? But unsure of how to do that?

## **UPDATE:**

I've managed to get each button to control their own table, however I have another issue now.

When I click one `load-more` button, it loads the next 8 rows as it should, when I click the other `load-more` button, it loads the next 8 rows that were loaded in the previous table, so it jumps from 8 to 17, 18, 19... etc

You can see here in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/pixelboutiqueuk-the-lessful/pen/JjogZXa?editors=1000

This is what I currently have after many tweaks:

```
         // load more buttons
    var songTotalRows = $('.songs-table tr').length;
    if ( songTotalRows > 8 ) {
        $('.songs-table').after('<div class="load-more"><input id="song-show" type="button" value="Load More" /></div>');
    }
    
    var albumTotalRows = $('.album-table tr').length;
    if ( albumTotalRows > 8 ) {
        $('.album-table').after('<div class="load-more"><input id="album-show" type="button" value="Load More" /></div>');
    }

    var totalrowshidden;
    var rows2display=8;
    var rem=0;
    var rowCount=0;
    var forCntr;
    var forCntr1;
    var MaxCntr=0;
    
    $('.hide').click(function() {
        var rowCount = $('.spotify-table tr').length;
        rowCount=rowCount/2;
        rowCount=Math.round(rowCount)
    
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            $('tr:nth-child('+ i +')').hide(300); 
        }                            
    });
    
    $('#song-show').click(function() {
        rowCount = $('.songs-table tr').length;
        MaxCntr=forStarter+rows2display;
    
        if (forStarter<=$('.songs-table tr').length) {
            for (var i = forStarter; i < MaxCntr; i++) {
             $('.songs-table tr:nth-child('+ i +')').show(200);
            }
            forStarter=forStarter+rows2display
        } else {
            $('#song-show').hide();
        }
    });
    
    $('#album-show').click(function() {
        rowCount = $('.album-table tr').length;
        MaxCntr=forStarter+rows2display;
    
        if (forStarter<=$('.album-table tr').length) {
            for (var i = forStarter; i < MaxCntr; i++) {
             $('.album-table tr:nth-child('+ i +')').show(200);
            }
            forStarter=forStarter+rows2display
        } else {
            $('#album-show').hide();
        }
    });
    
    var rowCount = $('.spotify-table tr').length;
    for (var i = $('.spotify-table tr').length; i > rows2display; i--) {
        rem=rem+1
        $('.spotify-table tr:nth-child('+ i +')').hide(200);
    }
    
    forCntr=$('.spotify-table tr').length-rem;
    forStarter=forCntr+1
```

Comment: What is the relevant html snippet for this?  You should probably assign show and hide as classes, instead of id's, at least if they are going to be assigned to two different objects (buttons).

Comment: I'm using the 'Table Press' plugin so I don't have the HTML i'm afraid.
Can I ask why classes and not IDS?

Comment: an id is meant to be a unique element identifier, in particular you might get unexpected behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-jquery-works-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I knew that. So I've changed them to classes now, but now both buttons control both tables. They need to control their own table only.

Comment: Well, you need to be able to associate the table where the event happens in your function. Assuming the table is the parent of your button,you can use the this element to get the relevant table, something like:  table= $(this).parent(); (rest of your function implementation)

Comment: This is where I'm at: https://codepen.io/pixelboutiqueuk-the-lessful/pen/JjogZXa