# Why does jQuery return more than one element when selecting by type and ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon something when I tried to debug a problem with non-unique ids on one of my sites.

I had a couple of checkboxes on them, all with the same id. While debugging I tried to find the offending elements and noticed that searching for them with jQuery, using only the id as the selector, didn't work, but the id was all I had in the console error message.

I have already resolved my problem in the meantime by making sure the checkboxes have unique ids (or don't have ids at all for that matter), but I'm intrigued on why these two jQuery calls give me different results:

```
jQuery('#edit-checkbox').length        // this always gives 1
jQuery('input#edit-checkbox').length   // this gives the correct number of elements
```

[See this fiddle for a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ockbgj10/)

Why do these selectors return different results? I'm sure someone can explain that to me here.

Comment: maybe because an ID is supposed to be unique. And if you call `#blabla` it will just call `document.getElementById(blabla)` which gives you back 1 result. if you put the second selector there might be some jquery filtering added which changes the outcome. So don't have duplicate IDs, it can mess everything up.

Comment: *"this always gives 1"* - That's exactly what it should do.  You're selecting by `id`, which is a unique identifier.  The fact that the second one finds more elements is by coincidence alone.  The HTML is invalid, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @isherwood: The root of the problem is the same.  The `id` values need to be unique.  Also, the linked duplicate does indeed *specifically* ask about jQuery.  The *answer* has nothing to do with jQuery, but the question does ask it.

Comment: @isherwood wrong!! ID's **must be unique** in html, the problem is in html, not in jquery

Comment: That oversimplifies and disregards a valid question.

Comment: @dippas the OP here is asking why there is a difference in the behaviour of the mentioned selectors. It is not a duplicate of the question you posted

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't  mark the question as duplicated

Comment: You're right, apologies.

Comment: If anyone cares `document.querySelectorAll('input#edit-checkbox').length` produces the same result. It's semi-interesting behavior based on invalid HTML.

Comment: Ah, great, the linked question's accepted answer solves the conundrum for me. Didn't find that when searching. @David I'm fully aware that this is not valid HTML, but "the behavior is undefined" is not a satisfying answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498617/368479 gives a good explanation of what happens.