# How to duplicate value from one input and put in others inputs JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created a script in JavaScript to take value from one input and place it in several inputs, but I have a problem that value is only put in the first input.

The JavaScript code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var $apartament = $('#value-apartament'),

$permetru = $('#put-value');

$apartament.on('input', function () {

$permetru.val($apartament.val());

});

});
```

The first input have the id: `#value-apartament` and the others have `#put-value` for copy the value from the first input and put for the rest of three.

image: https://prnt.sc/nyj_S9AjhaMW

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the # id attribute is used for unique elements. It is better to use . class attribute to select multiple input with the class of .put-value.

```
$('input#value-apartament').change(function() {
    $('input.put-value').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but i changed a little

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be used to identify a unique element of the DOM, so using #value-apartment is correct for the first input. But having the same id #put-value for the other three is wrong.

You should use a class for those 3 inputs, and you can select those using ($'.put-value')

Answer (score 0):

An ID should exist only once in the whole HTML document - use classes if you want to assign it to multiple elements. As answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-does-jquery-work-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id-value) question, jQuery will return the first element in the document with the id, and that is what happened for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).