# Javascript serialize array multiple forms issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

Hi All I have 2 arrays on one page and some buttons which are performing onclick ajax calls - the line I am using to serialize the array is as seen below:

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray();
```

however the wrong form is being serialized - is there anyway to do serialize array by name or ID of a form field - I know this will be an extremely easy solution - I am completely new to JS

Comment: You can use $('form#formid') to get the right form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. If you have an ID set up on this form element (and you usually should), just specify it in the selector:

```
var someFormData = $('#some_form_id').serializeArray();
var anotherFormData = $('#another_form_id').serializeArray();
```

Note that using it like this is preferable to `$('form#some_form_id')` - being more specific when using ID selector [**is not a good idea**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262147/1229023).

It's almost the same with names - you just have to use so-called `attribute selector`:

```
var someFormData = $('[name=some_form]').serializeArray();
var anotherFormData = $('[name=another_form]').serializeArray();
```

Comment: I never said it was impossible - in fact I mention the solution will be extremely easy I just didn't know how! Thankyou for the solution!